# Ubuntu Autopilot install instructions

Tags: 14.04, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

In the [Ubuntu Openstack installation instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot), it mentions at Step 1

> **Install Ubuntu Server on one of the machines with two network
>   interfaces**

But then it also says that each server must have two hard drives, so how do I install ubuntu server? Do I setup RAID 1 or do I install on the first hard drive and leave the second hard drive alone?

Clearer instructions regarding how to configure the two hard drives for the first Ubuntu server installation would be very helpful.

Comment: See 0xF2 answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/656436/installing-ubuntu-openstack-requires-at-least-five-machines-with-two-disks-two

Comment: i read that and i don't see the answer to my question there..i am not asking why i need 2 disks, i am asking how do i install the first ubuntu server on the first server? DO i setup RAID on the 2 disks or install on one disk? that is my question

Comment: My understanding from the question I linked to is that autopilot will configure one disk as boot and the other for being allocated to the Ceph OSD for data storage.

Comment: well step 1 says install ubuntu server, this is way before there is autopilot anywhere. So does this mean install the ubuntu server on 1 disk only? i think this is first step before autopilot comes in. And that is why i am asking the question

Comment: I believe so (if you only have 2 disks in the machine). I would reserve one for data storage. Again, this is my understanding based on the information I found. Any mistakes are mine.

Comment: Here is the error i get when i install one disk http://askubuntu.com/questions/743328/error-installing-ubuntu-14-04-lts-server

Comment: Attempts to access areas outside the disk are typically the result of a corrupt partition table. I suggest verifying the existing table against the actual geometry of the drive.

Answer (score 0):

That particular first machine will get MAAS and it does not need two disks.

Comment: Well UBUNTU stated that all 5 minimum machines must have 2 disks and 2 of the machines must have 2 network connections. And it states that step1 needs to be performed on one of the 2 that have the 2 network connections.